# Bash: How can I do the following operation in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following file content

```
051C
3B8E
```

Using a bash command I would like to format it to have the following output

```
1C05
8E3B
```

I need help to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed will do:

```
sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)/\2\1/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Read line by line and flip the substrings:

```
while read -r line; do  
    echo "${line:2:2}${line:0:2}"
done < file.txt
```